# E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed whenever trying to install any software or to update in Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux, package-management, apt, dpkg

```
#apt-get update

Fetched 26.5 MB in 3min 1s (146 kB/s)                                          

Output directory /var/lib/debtags/ does not exist
Reading package lists... Error!
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: i changed aLL that plzzz help me how can i resolve this

Comment: please anyone help by solving my error.

Comment: somebody please resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/debtags
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt update
```

If you get an error that says: `E: Lists directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing` run this command to make the missing directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

Comment: still not working #Karel I got same error

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo mkdir /var/lib/debtags
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/debtags’: File exists

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
cp: cannot stat '/var/backups/dpkg.status.0': No such file or directory

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/lock'
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory
removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_contrib_binary-i386_Packages'
removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_contrib_source_Sources'
removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_InRelease'
removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed '/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_main_source_Sources'

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo apt-get update
apt_pkg.Error: E:flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Problem opening , E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 192.95.30.159 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No suc

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: File exists

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade for this it complete some % and then shows ths error apt_pkg.Error: E:flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory), E:Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory), E:Problem opening , E:The package lists or status file cld nt b opnd
Reading package lists... Error!
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: I removed tag to windows 7 and i am using only single boot to kali linux 2.0